# create_padding_mask in Transformer code uses encoder input sequence for creating padding mask in 2nd attention block of the decoder

Tags: tensorflow, transformer-model

I am going through the Transformer code on tensorflow.org - https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/transformer

```
def create_masks(self, inp, tar):
    # Encoder padding mask (Used in the 2nd attention block in the decoder too.)
    padding_mask = create_padding_mask(inp)

    # Used in the 1st attention block in the decoder.
    # It is used to pad and mask future tokens in the input received by
    # the decoder.
    look_ahead_mask = create_look_ahead_mask(tf.shape(tar)[1])
    dec_target_padding_mask = create_padding_mask(tar)
    look_ahead_mask = tf.maximum(dec_target_padding_mask, look_ahead_mask)

    return padding_mask, look_ahead_mask
```

Transformer class has a method called create_masks which creates padding and look ahead mask.
I understand that padding mask for encoder should take input sequence(input to the encoder) for creating padding mask. However, what I do not understand is why should the input sequence to the encoder should be used for creating padding mask for second attention block of the decoder(first line of the code). I think the padding mask for decoder should be created using the target sequence(which is fed to the decoder).

Please help me understand why this is done.

Answer (score 0):

first you should understand the padding mask in encoder is applied along the axis of key in the attention score (if you view attention score as a 2d matrix, it's the j, or 2nd axis).
then come to decoder, encoder output provides key to the decoder attention layer (2nd attention layer in the decoder) while target input only provides query through decoder's 1st attention layer. since padding mask is applied along key axis, the padding mask should has the same dimension as source sentence length.

Comment: Why is padding mask applied only to key axis?

Comment: because Key axis the is actual weights you applied to value, and unwanted weights are you we should mask.

Comment: The padding is present on query axis as well, so the dot product between query and key will have values corresponding to padding on query. How is that right?